# Prove that ($x_n$) converges to the cube root of a

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

i) Let $s,a>0$ and $t=\frac{1}{3}(2s+a/s^2)$, use the Arithmetic-Geometric inequality to prove $t^3\geq a$.

Using the Arithmetic-Geometric inequality, I found

$$(a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_n)^{1/n} \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$$
$$t\geq (ssa/s^2)^{1/3} = a^{1/3}$$

ii) Let $a>0$, $x_1>0$, and define

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2x_n+a/x^2_n)$$

for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that ($x_n$) converges to the cube root of a.

I solved $i)$, but I can't find a way to solve $ii)$. I tried the ratio test, Cauchy sequence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x_n^3 \geq a$, we have $x_n \geq a x_n^{-2}$. But $x_{n+1}$ is simply the arithmetic average of the three numbers $x_n$, $x_n$, and $ax_n^{-2}$. Therefore
$\{x_n\}$ is a decreasing positive sequence, and so converges. Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$.
Then by the recurrence relation,
$$
3L =  \frac{a}{L^2} +2L.
$$
The only real solution is $\sqrt[3]{a}$.

This is a very old algorithm that was once used to approximate cube roots by hand.

Comment: Why is $x^3 > a $?

Comment: That was part i of your problem! I suppose technically, the very first number $x_1^3$ could be less than $a$ since it wasn't defined by the recurrence relation, but the cube of all the rest of the numbers in the sequence will be greater than or equal to $a$ so the sequence is still decreasing past that point.

Comment: Last thing. How does the recurrence relation work? I mean, how do you get 3L?

Comment: I just multiplied both sides by 3 because i didn't want to write a the fraction $\frac{1}{3}$. (I'm lazy.) But that's the standard trick for finding the limit of a sequence defined by a simple recurrence relation: substitute the limit $L$ wherever you see $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ etc, and solve. If the sequence converges, it will have to converge to one of the solutions of the equation.

Comment: Ok! I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $$x_n^3 \ge a \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \dfrac{a}{x_n^2} \le x_n \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_{n+1} \le x_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply Newton formula to f(x)=x^3-a. After simplication, you obtain what you wrote in ii).